# How to convert binary text to byte array

Tags: c#, c++, encoding, binary, byte

I have got a text file which name is "file.txt".
There is binary text like "`11100100100`" in that file and I am trying to read the file and convert the binary into a bytearray.

When I run the code it converts to ascii characters. Btw i am just checking the code from break points. I saw ASCII characters from there.

Here is the code

```
String^ fileName = "file.txt";
FileStream^ fs = gcnew FileStream(fileName, FileMode::Open);
BinaryReader^ br = gcnew BinaryReader(fs);
INT32 tmpInd = 0;
array<Byte^>^ byteArr = gcnew array<Byte^>(br->BaseStream->Length);
while(br->BaseStream->Position < br->BaseStream->Length){
    byteArr[tmpInd] = br->ReadByte();
    tmpInd++;
}
fs->Close();
```

Comment: To read a text file, you use the character encoding it was written with in a StreamReader or similar. See [How to: Read Text from a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file).

Comment: What language are you coding with (I guessed C# or maybe .net)? Is `Convert.ToByte` an option? What is your `file.txt` size when divided by 8?

Comment: Its c++/cli. I tried Convert::ToByte but again i saw ascii codes instead of byte array. File will have about 30 byte binary numbers. So i will need 30 byte when it is divided

Comment: I tried with streamreader and binaryreader but result is same. I am reading from text file but problem is i am reading as ascii characters which i dont want. If i give an example 1111000010010100 written in file.txt. And i want to see byteArr[0]=11110000 and byteArr[1]=10010100 or at least their hex version. But now its like 49 49 49 48 49 48. Because 48 is 0 49 is 1 in ascii code